# Capture object property value, from incoming request in spring-cloud-gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-reactor

I have a `spring-cloud-gateway` configuration like the one below:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
                  .route(r -> r.path("/api/bank/account/user/**") //intercept calls to
                               .uri("http://mrq-bank-account.cloud.host/")
                               .id("bankModule"))
                  .build();
}
```

This route is expected to accept two types of requests going to:

```
/api/bank/account/user/savingsAccount
```

and

```
/api/bank/account/user/studentAccount
```

The first request  carries a `SavingsAccount` object, and the second a `StudentAccount` object. Both of these objects have a `userRef:String` property which I need to extract. Is it possible to do that somehow on the `cloud-gateway-configuration` by adding to it?

Basically I am trying to find out how to extract a property from an object being carried by an incoming request in a spring-cloud-gateway configuration like the one above.

This is the library method, I think could be used to achieve that:

```
package org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder;


    /**
 * This predicate is BETA and may be subject to change in a future release. A
 * predicate that checks the contents of the request body
 * @param inClass the class to parse the body to
 * @param predicate a predicate to check the contents of the body
 * @param <T> the type the body is parsed to
 * @return a {@link BooleanSpec} to be used to add logical operators
 */
public <T> BooleanSpec readBody(Class<T> inClass, Predicate<T> predicate) {
    return asyncPredicate(
            getBean(ReadBodyRoutePredicateFactory.class).applyAsync(c -> c.setPredicate(inClass, predicate)));
}
```

But I would want to use that to extract the value of one of the properties of the read object and then use that value to call a service that will return a hostname - the value that must ultimately be used from the `uri()` method

This method from `org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder` also looks useful

```
    /**
 * A filter which change the URI the request will be routed to by the Gateway.
 * @param determineRequestUri a {@link Function} which takes a
 * {@link ServerWebExchange} and returns a URI to route the request to
 * @return a {@link GatewayFilterSpec} that can be used to apply additional filters
 */
public GatewayFilterSpec changeRequestUri(Function<ServerWebExchange, Optional<URI>> determineRequestUri) {
    return filter(new AbstractChangeRequestUriGatewayFilterFactory<Object>(Object.class) {
        @Override
        protected Optional<URI> determineRequestUri(ServerWebExchange exchange, Object config) {
            return determineRequestUri.apply(exchange);
        }
    }.apply(c -> {
    }));
}
```

Comment: Does gateway need to do this?

Comment: It would be convenient. I have a client sending a request, three instances of the same microservice project running on a cloud and a gateway project inbetween. Since these three instances have the same endpoints, what changes is the hostname. The way I find the hostname is by extracting the userRef property inside the object being carried as a parameter by the client request, and then using that userRef to call a custom discovery service which will return to me the correct hostname.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57335022/spring-cloud-gateway-routing-based-on-content-of-the-request-body

Comment: Not quite. I have already gone through that post. Thank you though

Comment: there is a `readBodyPredicate`

Comment: Could you please post an example?

Comment: @spencergibb I found this relevant resource, which I believe you have authored, but I cannot open the link. Could you please share? It is this one:
http://git.awoo.men/github/spring-cloud-gateway/commits/gateway-fu

Comment: that's an experiment. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/master/spring-cloud-gateway-sample/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/sample/GatewaySampleApplication.java#L69

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain how I can use the value read? Is it possible to read one of the properties of the body and save it in a parameter?